# On-Prem Linux LDAP server synced via LDAPS with O365 AAD DS (Without AAD Connect)?

Tags: ldap, entra-id, entra-domain-services

If you have an on-prem Linux LDAP server, is it possible to sync your on-prem accounts with your O365 Azure Active Directory Domain Services?

We want the O365 AAD DS to be the "source of truth" and we want to join our on-prem VMs to our on-prem domain to enable single sign-on with O365 accounts.

We would of course use secure LDAP (LDAPS).

Comment: Ignoring the Linux LDAP aspect of the question (because I don't know about that), if you sync your on premises users to Office 365 then your on premises directory is the "source of truth". You cannot sync your on premises directory to Office 365 while maintaining Office 365 as the "source of truth". With the exception of Office 365 Groups writeback, objects are mastered on premises, not in Office 365.

Comment: I assume you're taking about using AAD Connect? I realize it won't work with that scenario. I'm wondering if LDAP sync would work differently.

Comment: I haven't heard of any other method or mechanism for syncing an on premises directory other than Azure AD Connect and I haven't heard of any support for syncing a directory other than AD.